# How do I toggle an application's menu?

Tags: menu

is it possible to toggle (show/hide) the appmenu ? I've disabled the globalmenu, because i don't like the behavior.

[image: app menus]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than reinstalling the global menubar, each program you use has it's own settings for their menus (the "app menus").

---

**Terminal**
Right click and de-select "Show Menubar"

[image]

---

**FireFox**
Go to ▸ View ▸ Toolbars ▸ Menu Bar

[image]

---

**VLC**
Right click ▸ View ▸ Minimal Interface

[image]

---

**Nautilus**
(File manager) Not possible in current versions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround. Switch on global menu feature back. And then you can run any program not using global menu, for instance:

`UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 inkscape`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a HUGE lot!!! if you answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/758513/how-to-ensure-all-applications-menu-will-be-accessible-in-any-way-at-any-wind) I will accept there too! thx!!!!!